# Javascript & Wordpress: Flickering of content when displaying & hiding posts via filter buttons

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am using a group of filter-button at the top of a page to turn on and off the display of posts, depending on their respective category. To do so I am using the following javascript:

```
<script>
    var $btns = $('.btn').click(function() {

      if (this.id == 'all') {
        $('.projekte > .post').fadeIn(300);
      } else {
        $('.projekte > .post').not($el).fadeOut(300);
        var $el = $('.' + this.id).fadeIn(300);

      }
      $btns.removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    })
</script>
```

Turning on and off the posts belonging to the respective catergory which the button which was clicked is tied to works perfectly fine, but unfortunately there is an ugly flicker when new content is being displayed and the post which is hidden disappears.

Is there a way for me to fix is? For example by hiding the old post first and then loading the new one? How can I implement something like this in my javascript?

Here is the code of the entire page (the page itself can be visited here: http://udkdev.skopec.de/category/studierende/):

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
</div>
<br>
<div class="wrapper-offset-fix wrapper-studierende">
<div class="projekte content">

    <div class="button-group filters-button-group">
        <button class="projekt-btn btn"         id="category-stud-sose17">      SoSe 2017           </button>
        <button class="projekt-btn btn"         id="category-stud-wise1617">    WiSe 2016/17        </button>
        <button class="projekt-btn btn"         id="category-wise-201415">      SoSe 2016           </button>
        <button class="projekt-btn btn"         id="category-sose-14">          WiSe 2015/16        </button>
        <button class="projekt-btn btn"         id="category-sose-14">          SoSe 2015           </button>
        <button class="projekt-btn btn"         id="category-sose-14">          WiSe 2014/15        </button>

    </div>

    <?php if (have_posts()): ?>
        <?php while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>

        <div <?php post_class(); ?>>

    <?php 
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                the_post_thumbnail('full');
            } ?> 

    <?php the_content(); ?>

            </a>
        <!--<div class="meta">Tags: <?php the_tags( '', ', ', '<br />' ); ?> </div>-->
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else : ?>
        <h2>Couldn’t find any articles!</h2>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>

<script>
    var $btns = $('.btn').click(function() {

      if (this.id == 'all') {
        $('.projekte > .post').fadeIn(300);
      } else {
        var $el = $('.' + this.id).fadeIn(300);
        $('.projekte > .post').not($el).fadeOut(300);
      }
      $btns.removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    })
</script> 

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```